# Reloading data when clicking back bar button of an UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have an UINavigationController and it has an UITableViewController as its root controller. I reload the data for the table view in viewWillAppear. When I select an item in the table view it will push an new UIViewController with which the user could edit the data that will be shown in the table view, and then I clicked Back of the navigation, viewWillAppear of the UITableViewController was just not called and the data was not reloaded.

So in this case where could I reload the data for the table view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is to use `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. There are two methods available:

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated animated: Bool)
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated animated: Bool)
```

In your `UITableViewController`(root) you should add `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and method `navigationControllerWillShowViewController` will be called when you are going back. Here's an example:

```
class RootTableViewController: UITableViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    ...
    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated animated: Bool) {
        //Will run  
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct to pass data back but in this case if all he is looking to do is reload the table he should put it in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Also thanks! Your answer didn't help me on this question but it is helpful for improving another place in my code.

Answer (score 0):

viewWillAppear is called when you hit the back button. Just put a log in there if you don't believe me! Most likely the table is not reloading the way you want it to because there is something wrong with the table datasource.

Comment: Thanks! What you said helped me a lot. I am new to iOS and I don't know that UITableView accepts reloadData messages. I just reloaded the data cached in the controller but forgot to notify the table view to reload from the data source.